# Why did my lightning components stop showing up on my record pages in my scratch org after including my namespace?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, namespace, flexipages, custom-permission

I am using custom permissions to control when my lightning component appears on a given flexipage record page. The intent here is to make it easy for an admin to use a UI that I made to toggle visibility of the components by toggling this permission into and out of a permission set that users of my managed package already were assigned earlier.

Here is the XML for the lead record page (`MyCustomLeadRecordPage.flexipage-meta.xml`) for context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>collapsed</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>hideChatterActions</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>numVisibleActions</name>
                <value>3</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>force:highlightsPanel</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>header</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>hideUpdateButton</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>variant</name>
                <value>linear</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>runtime_sales_lead:pathAssistant</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>subheader</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>runtime_sales_activities:activityPanel</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>activityTabContent</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>force:detailPanel</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>detailTabContent</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>forceChatter:recordFeedContainer</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>feedTabContent</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>active</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>activityTabContent</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Standard.Tab.activity</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>detailTabContent</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Standard.Tab.detail</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>feedTabContent</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Standard.Tab.collaborate</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>newsTabContent</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Standard.Tab.news</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>tabs</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>tabs</name>
                <value>tabs</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tabset</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>main</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>displayOption</name>
                <value>BOTH</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>runtime_sales_merge:mergeCandidatesPreviewCard</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>relatedListComponentOverride</name>
                <value>NONE</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>rowsToDisplay</name>
                <value>10</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>showActionBar</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>force:relatedListContainer</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>relatedListTabContent</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>active</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>relatedListTabContent</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Standard.Tab.relatedLists</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>sidebartabs</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>CustomComponent1</componentName>
            <visibilityRule>
                <criteria>
                    <leftValue>{!$Permission.CustomPermission.Lead_Record_Install_App}</leftValue>
                    <operator>EQUAL</operator>
                    <rightValue>true</rightValue>
                </criteria>
            </visibilityRule>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>CustomComponent2</componentName>
            <visibilityRule>
                <criteria>
                    <leftValue>{!$Permission.CustomPermission.Lead_Record_Responses}</leftValue>
                    <operator>EQUAL</operator>
                    <rightValue>true</rightValue>
                </criteria>
            </visibilityRule>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>tabs</name>
                <value>sidebartabs</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tabset</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>sidebar</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>Lead Record Page</masterLabel>
    <parentFlexiPage>runtime_sales_lead__Lead_rec_L</parentFlexiPage>
    <sobjectType>Lead</sobjectType>
    <template>
        <name>flexipage:recordHomeWithSubheaderTemplateDesktop</name>
    </template>
    <type>RecordPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

That flexipage XML used to work perfectly before I added my namespace into my scratch org (it used to be blank):

`sfdx-project.json` included for context: (namespace used to be "")

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [{
        "path": "force-app/main",
        "default": true
    },
    {
        "path": "force-app/main/crud-fls",
        "default": false
    }],
    "namespace": "mynamespace",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "46.0"
}
```

I added in the namespace to my scratch orgs so that I could appropriately use that namespace in custom labels and translations and I would rather not switch it back if I can help it.

Does anyone know why visibility based on custom permissions broke here so that the record page thinks that the user doesn't have the custom permissions, even though the permissions are present? The visibility based on custom permissions still works correctly on the flexipages I made that aren't an override for record pages, oddly enough.

And as a related followup question: what do I need to do to get my record flexipage to go back to working with my custom permissions now that namespacing is turned on?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Suggest raising a support case.

Comment: Have you done this namespace switch-on by creating entirely new scratch orgs and deploying all your code to those new scratch orgs? I see you are using expressions for th custom permission access only in the page... so that should be namespace compatible... did you try explicitly adding the namespace prefix on the custom permission names?

Comment: @Phil W I did and no luck. It does not work properly and that’s the core issue

Comment: So the issue is that the expressions like ```{!$Permission.CustomPermission.Lead_Record_Install_App}``` fail when a namespace is involved, and even changing this to ```{!$Permission.CustomPermission.mynamespace__Lead_Record_Install_App}``` doesn't correct the behaviour (substituting the actual namespace prefix for "mynamespace" of course)?

Comment: @PhilW I will try that now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It should automatically do this so this seems bug even though manually doing it fix it

Comment: @PhilW I tried switching it to `{!$Permission.CustomPermission.mynamespace__Lead_Record_Install_App}` and it still fails.

Comment: @RobertHyatt, I assume you replaced "mynamespace" here with your actual namespace prefix, yes? If this still fails then there is a bug (as Mohith suggests) that you are unable to work around.

Comment: @PhilW Its a bug as far as i tested. Does not work within namespace. I request if someone raises case let me know the case number so i can channel it to right team

Comment: @PhilW Yes, I used my actual namespace in my test. When I post to public forums like this I choose to anonymize my code to not use real namespaces and such.

Comment: Right thing to do @RobertHyatt - I was just checking as that wasn't 100% clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been identified as a bug. 
Known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SosdQAC